# plot bar graph from colSums in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R (a dataframe), where I would like to compute the total for each variable.

```
         Score
Alison     1  
Abun       5 
Heidy      7
```

I would like to turn the table into something like this so that I can create plots:

```
Name     Score
Alison     1  
Abun       5 
Heidy      7
```

May I know how would I be able to achieve that?

Comment: If you just want a boring old plot, there's nothing stopping you from using the `data.frame` - `barplot(dat$Score, names.arg=rownames(dat))`

Comment: You may try `tibble::rownames_to_column(df, var = "name")`.

Comment: or `barplot(t(data))`

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @Park, you can first turn the rownames into a column. Then, you can plot it using `ggplot`.

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble::rownames_to_column(data, var = "name") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = Score, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity")
```

Output

[image]

Data

```
data <- structure(list(Score = c(1, 5, 7)),
                  class = "data.frame",
                  row.names = c("Alison", "Abun", "Heidy"))
```